# Why Oracle 19c Database EM Express Webpage is not opening in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I have recently installed Oracle Database 19c on my Laptop which has Windows 10 OS. Now, I want to open the **localhost:5500/em** page in Microsoft Edge browser, but when I try to do so, the webpage does not open and it says ***localhost** refused to connect*.
But in the SQLPLUS command prompt I am able to login successfully and execute queries.
Please help me resolving this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `https://` or `http://`? Do you have an SSL certificate for the Enterprise Manager? Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1:5500/em` instead?

Comment: @Johnakahot2use Yes I've tried **http://127.0.0.1:5500/em** but its not working. And I'm using **http://** . I don't know about the SSL certificate, kindly tell me how to check?

Comment: Does it work with some other browser?

Comment: @KalpadiptyaRoy By default EM Express is set with `https` protocol, try [localhost](https://localhost:5500/em) or just add  prefix `https://`(tested with 19c installation)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open the localhost:5500/em

What makes you think that the web site is being offered on port 5500?

I don't know about the Express version, but full-blown Enterprise Manager is provided by a running, Middleware process.  Is there a Window Service that you need to start (or, for whatever reason, has *failed* to start?)

> ... in the SQLPLUS command prompt I am able to login successfully ...

That's because the Database and the Web Site that you use to *manage* the Database are two completely separate things.

Comment: W. I think the website is offered on the port 5500 because at the end of Oracle 19c Installation, a message was shown with the link ```localhost:5500/em``` and it was written that I can access the Enterprise Manager from there.

Comment: @Phil w - " don't know about the Express version, but full-blown Enterprise Manager is provided by a running, Middleware process" .. EM Express runs as a service inside the database, not as a middleware.